# cakephp 3.0 blog tutorial authentication error

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm a newbie to cakephp.. I have started it directly from 3.0

I have followed the BLOG tutorial 1,2 and am facing an error in the Blog Tutorial - [Authentication and Authorization](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

```
// src/Controller/UsersController.php
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
parent::beforeFilter($event);
// Allow users to register and logout.
// You should not add the "login" action to allow list. Doing so would
// cause problems with normal functioning of AuthComponent.
$this->Auth->allow(['add', 'logout']);
}
```

I'm getting the error when i try to access the /users/add page.

```
Error: Call to a member function allow() on a non-object 
File : src\Controller\UsersController.php
```

What is wrong? Isn't it supposed to allow to add users without authentication?

Comment: Did you add `auth` as component in `AppController`?

Comment: It would be this section in that tutorial: `Authentication (Login and Logout)` http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: Yes this is present `public function initialize()
    {
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Articles',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ]
        ]);
    }`

Comment: Ok... cool. Then post as much content from your `UsersController.php` file as possible, specially the function José mentioned in his answer below for anyone here to analyze

Comment: @Andre If you can make your first comment as the answer, I will make it as the current answer. It was a big story but I found out that what you indicated was the problem. Thanks man

Comment: Not a problem! Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `Auth Component` is correctly loaded in your `AppController.php` file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Oldskool... if you had checked comments in the Author's post you would have noticed that I had placed this same "critique" and he requested I make that the answer so he can accept and close this... Is that why you decided to DELETE this? By deleting without checking, you prevented him from accepting this as the answer that brought him to a solution....

Comment: You are responding to a question with a question, furthermore there's no elaboration in your answer as of why this step is required. In itself, without reading the comments, this is a poor answer and hence I voted to delete it.

Comment: @Oldskool, it is no longer a question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call `parent::initialize()` in your UsersController.php if you implement the `public initialize()` method